# Stripe Display Connected Account Balance to User

Tags: node.js, swift, stripe-payments

I am integrating Stripe into my ridesharing app and I was wondering if it was possible to display the Connect Account balance to the user in Swift?

Stripe has an option to retrieve`stripe.balance.retrieve({})`, but that is showing the balance in the console.

Is it possible to pass this value to the frontend in Swift with a GET request and storing the value in a UITextLabel?

I tried something with this GET request, but I can only get it to display in the Swift console?

```
func readBalance(userID: String)
{
    var viewProfileComponents = URLComponents(string: "http://myWebsite/payment/payout")!
    viewProfileComponents.queryItems = [
        URLQueryItem(name: "userID", value: userID)
    ]
    var request = URLRequest(url: viewProfileComponents.url!)  // Pass Parameter in URL
    print (viewProfileComponents.url!)

    request.httpMethod = "GET" // GET METHOD

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil){  // error handling responses.
            print (error as Any)
        }
        else if let data = data {
            print(data)
            let userInfoString:NSString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            if let data = userInfoString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json as Any)
                    if let userInfo = json!["data"]
                    {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.balanceAmount.text? = (userInfo["balance"] as! String)
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }

            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Where `balanceAmount` is my UITextLabel

**GET Request**

```
router.get("/payout", function (req, res) {
var userID = req.query.userID;
console.log('get payout body ', req.body);

db.query(`select \"Users\".\"stripeAccountID\", \"Users\".\"balance\" from database.\"Users\" where \"Users\".\"userID\" ='${userID}'`) 
.then(function(data) {

const accBalance = stripe.balance.retrieve({
    stripe_account: data.stripeAccountID
}).then(db.any(`UPDATE database.\"Users\" set \"Users\".\"balance\" = '${accBalance}' where \"Users\".\"userID\" ='${userID}'`));
console.log(data.balance)
console.log('data: ', data)
  res.status(200).json({
  status: 'Success',
  data: data,
  message:  'Retrieved Account Balance.'
});
  })
.catch(function(error){
  console.log('Error fetching payout', error);
});
})
```

**Stripe Server GET Response**
[image: node GET]

**Xcode Console Response**
[image: xcode get response]

I know the Xcode GET response doesn't match, the `balance` in Xcode is being grabbed from the Database value.

If there is any other information that could help, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just curious, what is the shape of your JSON response? do you mind pasting a sample from your server side call?

Comment: @wsw I just added the console responses from both Node and Swift. Please let me know if these are what you're looking for